# WinJS.Application.onsetting never fires

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-store

For my Windows 8 Store JS app, I'd like to add a privacy statement button to the settings charm. However, registering the following callback function does nothing:

```
WinJS.Application.onsettings = function (e) {
    var vector = e.detail.e.request.applicationCommands;
    var cmd1 = new Windows.UI.ApplicationSettings.SettingsCommand("privacy", "Privacy Statement", function () {
        window.open('http://lolkitten.org/app-privacy-policy');
    });
    vector.append(cmd1);
};
```

This snippet is executed on the jQuery `$(document).ready` event. My HTML file contains the following W8-specific JS

```
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/base.js"></script>
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/ui.js"></script>
```

My settings charm is unchanged, and no error occurs when opening it. Also, setting a debug point inside the callback function never leads to a stop, so I guess the callback never fires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a windows 8 (xaml/C#) developer. Have you seen [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/644119/Adding-Privacy-Setting-to-Charm-Windows-JavaScri) url?.

Comment: My app was missing the `default.js`, which somehow initializes the app for such functionality.